# Using a dropdown vs an input stepper for a product page recommendation?

Tags: e-commerce, dropdown, shopping-cart, product-details

I'm working on a web platform and an app, and for the product page, I'm not sure which is the best solution: using a dropdown OR an input stepper.
When looking online, it seems like big e-commerce shops are using both, but I think it also has something to do with the number of products the user is usually buying. In this case, I'm still waiting on some data, but I think our users usually buy 1 product. I chose the dropdown for the web, because it looks more minimalist, aesthetically. For the app, I chose a stepper because it has more control on a small screen.

What would you say is the best case to use the dropdown vs input stepper to select the number of products?

[image: Amazon web example]
[image: Amazon app example]

Answer (score 2):

There's a great table shown in an article created by Nielsen Norman group regarding [input steppers usage](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/input-steppers/).

| Use Input Steppers When | Do Not Use Input Steppers When |
| --- | --- |
| The numeric field has a most commonly selected value and most users will not deviate insignificantly from it (e.g., number of passengers). | The numeric field can take a wide range of values (e.g., age), with no one value being entered significantly more often than others. |
| The numeric field needs to be adjusted by a small, discrete amount or precision is not important (e.g., number of bedrooms). | The numeric field is continuous and the exact value is important. |
| There is enough room for generous spacing of the stepper segments. | Limited design space for button layout would make the stepper segments small or cramped. |

[Source](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/input-steppers/)

Based on the article and your needs I'd suggest you using input steppers, **BUT**.

It's important to mention the greatness of dropdown menus, especially when it comes to the UX in e-commerce. [Dropdown boxes and menus are overused and clunky **but can be useful for revealing a list of options or commands**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/drop-down-menus/).

I've created a chart representing a quantity-click relationship. Y axis is representing clicks and the anger of the user. As it could be seen from the chart it's better to use input stepper if users usually choose between 1-3 items because it requires less or same amount of user clicks compared to dropdown menu's. After that we can see the greatness of dropdown menu - it stays consistently at the 2 clicks, while input stepper exponentially increases until the infinity. Personally I'd rather go either for dropdown menu implementation as it would consistently require only 2 clicks at all times or use an input stepper with additional input methods (*there's a section inside an article about input steppers regarding additional input methods*).

To summarize: Input steppers are better if users order between 1-3 items, but dropdown menu is a safe option to maintain the same amount of clicks for all users.

[image: Quantity-click relationship]